# Handlebars custom helper is not invoked

Tags: templates, handlebars.js, helper

I have created a custom handlebars helper and I have noticed that the function is not called when rendering template (no output from console.log('Current Context')).

I have the following files:

Main razor page that has following includes:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/ICanHaz.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Handlebars.registerHelper('method', function (status) {
        console.log("Current Context");
        console.log(this);
        return '<p>Test</p>';
    });
</script>
```

Template

```
<script type="text/html" id="TableBody">
    <tr>
        <td>{{method 5}}</td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Backbone view

```
this.setElement(ich.TableBody(this.model.attributes));
```

Comment: does the template actually render with the type set to type="text/html" instead of type="text/x-handlebars-template" ?

Comment: Nope, it throws Uncaught TypeError exception.